# How to get value from StreamController?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get  value 'data' from StreamController

> `stream.listen((data) {print('$data');}) ;`

// global.dart

```
final StreamController ctrl = StreamController();
```

// father.dart

```
onSubmitted: (value) {
    debugPrint('Send Data: '+areaNameTextController.text);
    ctrl.sink.add('Receive Data: '+areaNameTextController.text);},
```

//children.dart

```
GoogleMap(
...
onTap: (LatLng latlng){
 ctrl.stream.listen((data) {
  print('$data');} ) ;
  
  Marker(
  ...
  infoWindow:InfoWindow(title:'///Where I want use data///'),
  );
   
  }
)
```

Comment: sorry I will re-post full code

Answer (score 3):

In my project I use a wrapper around StreamController.
It lets me to get the very last value from StreamController.

Here is the code:

```
class SimpleStream<T> {
  final StreamController<T> _stream = StreamController<T>();

  Sink<T> get _input => _stream.sink;

  Stream<T> get output => _stream.stream;

  T? _currentValue;

  T? get current => _currentValue;

  void update(T value) {
    _currentValue = value;
    _input.add(value);
  }

  void close() {
    _stream.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say `StreamController` and In your question you wrote`Stream`.
Should fix like that.

```
streamController.stream.listen(
  (event) => print('Event: $event'),
  onDone: () => print('Done'),
  onError: (error) => print(error),
);
```

Comment: sorry,I  posted new one

Comment: You should use stream listening in the ```init``` state of the ```Stateful``` class and then button should only do hide and show that data, get from stream.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I use like that for pull to do pull to refresh. Listening is only purpose for listening from coming data and not for action. If you want to check something that come from BLOC controller, first listening in `init` state and use with action from that checked data.

```
  void initState() {
    _houseVisitBloc.listAppHouseVisitStream().listen((ResponseOb res) {
      if (res.message == MsgState.data) {
        List<HouseVisitAppData> listenList = res.data;
        mainPullList = listenList;
        print(listenList.toString());
        if (mainPullList == listenList) {
          _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
        }
        if (res.data == MsgState.data) {
          _refreshController.loadComplete();
        }
      }
      if (res.data != MsgState.data) {
        _refreshController.loadNoData();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```